# Bash command assigned to variable stays empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, xargs

I have few commands following each other after an `xargs`. Funnily enough the command works fine if just echo it out to `stdout`. When I try to assign it to a variable, the variable stays empty. See below:

```
$~ ./somescript | grep -f fc.samples  | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} | tr '/' '\t' | cut -f9;"
sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4
sample5
sample6
sample7
sample8
$~
```

Trying to assign it to a variable and then echo it results in empty lines:

```
$~ ./somescript | grep -f fc.samples  | xargs -I {} sh -c "sample=$(echo {} | tr '/' '\t' | cut -f9); echo $sample; "







$~
```

I have tried multiple variations of it and cannot figure out what I am getting wrong. Can somebody spot the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this one? `sample=$(./somescript | grep -f fc.samples  | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} | tr '/' '\t' | cut -f9;")`

Comment: No, I did not - the idea of assigning to `sample` is for later use within the xargs commands - I think this would not work out for me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` chars for the `sh -c` command, otherwise the `$( )` and `$sample` part will be handled by the current shell rather than the `sh -c`.

```
... | xargs -I {} sh -c "sample=\$(echo {} | tr '/' '\t' | cut -f9); echo \$sample; "
```

Or you can consider using single quotes for outer quoting.

```
... | xargs -I {} sh -c 'sample=$(echo {} | tr "/" "\t" | cut -f9); echo $sample; '
```

Comment: Great! Quote switching... Thanks for your help - spot on!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass the argument *to* `sh`, rather than try to dynamically create a shell command by embedding the result. (Also, unless the purpose of `tr` is to create *additional* fields in a string like `foo/bar\tbaz`, you can just tell `cut` to use `/` as the field delimiter instead of using the default of a tab.)

```
# script='sample=$(echo "$1" | cut -d / -f9); echo "$sample"'

script='sample=$(echo "$1" | tr '/' '\t' | cut -f9); echo "$sample"'
./somescript | grep -f fc.samples  | 
  xargs -I {} sh -c "$script" _ {}
```

`_` is a dummy argument used to set `$0` in the shell.